# Framework CFBundleIdentifier Collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cfbundleidentifier

I've made a custom SDK using Cocoa Touch Framework (followed these instructions to make it https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios8-remix/) .

One app, that is using this SDK is already uploaded to app store and is reviewed by apple and all is well. 
Now I'm trying to submit second app to App store. All is well on the xCode, it shows that upload was completed successfully, but few minutes after uploading I get a letter that says:

> CFBundleIdentifier Collision - The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value
>   'com.company.MySDK' of 'myApp.app/Frameworks/MySDK.framework' is
>   already in use by another application.

I don’t understand why apple even checks the app framework's bundleidentifier. Looks like there are lot of similar issues with using different bundles, but I haven not found a fix that would work for this issue.

Would be really thankful for help, thanks!

Comment: Should've mentioned the "ITMS-9051" in CFBundleIdentifier Collision. I could not find your answer until i search without the error. I think most people will google by the error code. This comment should help to find it now tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it was caused by framework's .plist keyword *CFBundlePackageType* that was using the default value *APPL* but had to be changed to *FMWK* (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-111321).

Comment: Dude you are a hero for finding this :D

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Nested frameworks use "Do Not Embed" in the general tab-> framework and libraries
for example:
your project uses framework ***A*** and

and framework A uses frameworks B, C, ... Do not Embed these frameworks

Comment: This answer saved me