# iOS - watchOS App ITMS-90806: CFBundleIdentifier collision Alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, watchos, app-store-connect

I have an app for iOS and watchOS, both using Alamofire to communicate to our server for authentication and notification responses.  After successfully uploading my app from Xcode I received the following email from App Store Connect.

> "ITMS-90806: CFBundleIdentifier collision - Each bundle must have a
>   unique bundle identifier. The bundle identifier
>   'org.alamofire.Alamofire' is used in the bundles
>   '[Alamofire.framework, Alamofire.framework]'"

This appears to be a new issue based on the relative few things I've found regarding this, and nothing specifically for Alamofire.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - watchOS App publishing issue CFBundleIdentifier collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723390/ios-watchos-app-publishing-issue-cfbundleidentifier-collision)

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire 4.9.0 and 5.0.0-rc.1 have been updated to have dynamic bundle identifiers. However, if you're using CocoaPods, it needs an update to support the dynamic identifiers.